# How to select a single JSON object out of several and navigate its hierarchy in python

Tags: javascript, python, json, beautifulsoup

I have a webpage that contains several javascript elements. I only want to access one, named `SOURCE.pdp.propertyJSON`, and access the attributes in a PYTHONIC manner.

An edited (for the sake of readability) version of the HTML sourcecode is below; following is my python code.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
SOURCE = SOURCE || {};
SOURCE.pdp = SOURCE.pdp || {};
SOURCE.pdp.propertyJSON = {
  "neighborhood": "Westwood",
  "neighborhoodId": 7187,
  "zipCode": "90024",
  "city": "Los Angeles",
  "county": "Los Angeles",
  "countyFIPS": "06037",
  "stateCode": "CA",
  "stateName": "California",
  "type": "CONDO",
  "typeDisplay": "Condo",
  "numBedrooms": "2",
  "numBathrooms": 2,
  "numFullBathrooms": 2,
  "numBeds": 2,
  "indexSource": "Assessor",
  "isForeclosure": false,
  "isOpaqueBAL": false,
  "foreclosureStatus": "",
  "isSrpFeatured": false,
  "price": null,
  "sqft": 1321,
  "formattedBedAndBath": "2bd, 2 full ba",
  "formattedSqft": "1,321 sqft"
}
pdp_location_data = {
  "neighborhood": {
    "locationId": "87308",
    "name": "Westwood",
    "locationType": "neighborhood",
    "altId": "7187"
  },
  "state": {
    "locationId": "5",
    "name": "California",
    "locationType": "state",
    "altId": "CA"
  },
  "county": {
    "locationId": "57",
    "name": "Los Angeles County",
    "locationType": "county",
    "altId": "06037"
  },
  "city": {
    "locationId": "22637",
    "name": "Los Angeles",
    "locationType": "city",
    "altId": "4396"
  },
  "zipCode": {
    "locationId": "76090",
    "name": "90024",
    "locationType": "zipCode",
    "altName": "90024",
    "altId": "90024"
  }
};
SOURCE.pdp.isCountySupportsValuation = true;
SOURCE.pdp.isInHighDemandRegion = false;
var _SPANLONG = pdp_location_data.longitude;
var _SPANLAT = pdp_location_data.latitude;
var _CENLONG = pdp_location_data.longitude;
var _CENLAT = pdp_location_data.latitude;
</script>
```

Beware the ugly python!

```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
  import requests as rq

  url = 'https://www.SOURCE.com'
  source_code = rq.get(url).text
  soupcon = bsoup(source_code,"html.parser")
  souper = soupcon.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})

  for line in souper:
      if format(line).find('SOURCE.pdp.propertyJSON') != -1:
            parts = format(line).split(',')

  for var in parts:
        if var.find('zipCode') != -1:
            zipCode = var.split(':')[1].strip('"')
        elif var.find('numBathrooms') != -1:
            numBathrooms = var.split(':')[1].strip('"')
```

As you can see, I am currently accessing the JS object I want by finding all script elements that are of the type text/javascript, iterating through them to find the script that contains the object that I want, then splitting the entire script by the JS separator `','`, and identifying elements of the JS object by searching through them for my key words. Not an ideal solution.

Comment: Instead of making it chatty, you should focus on problem. Explain what you are trying to achieve and what have you tried.

Comment: I hope the edits made it less chatty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the data as a dict using json.loads:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import re
from json import loads
source = """<script type="text/javascript">  SOURCE = SOURCE || {};
  SOURCE.pdp = SOURCE.pdp || {};
  SOURCE.pdp.propertyJSON = {    "neighborhood": "Westwood",    "neighborhoodId": 7187,    "zipCode": "90024",    "city": "Los Angeles",    "county": "Los Angeles",    "countyFIPS": "06037",    "stateCode": "CA",    "stateName": "California",    "type": "CONDO",    "typeDisplay": "Condo",    "numBedrooms": "2",    "numBathrooms": 2,    "numFullBathrooms": 2,    "numBeds": 2,    "indexSource": "Assessor",    "isForeclosure": false,    "isOpaqueBAL": false,    "foreclosureStatus": "",    "isSrpFeatured": false,    "price": null,    "sqft": 1321,    "formattedBedAndBath": "2bd, 2 full ba",    "formattedSqft": "1,321 sqft"  }  pdp_location_data = {    "neighborhood": {      "locationId": "87308",      "name": "Westwood",      "locationType": "neighborhood",      "altId": "7187"    },    "state": {      "locationId": "5",      "name": "California",      "locationType": "state",      "altId": "CA"    },    "county": {      "locationId": "57",      "name": "Los Angeles County",      "locationType": "county",      "altId": "06037"    },    "city": {      "locationId": "22637",      "name": "Los Angeles",      "locationType": "city",      "altId": "4396"    },    "zipCode": {      "locationId": "76090",      "name": "90024",      "locationType": "zipCode",      "altName": "90024",      "altId": "90024"    }  };
   SOURCE.pdp.isCountySupportsValuation = true;
    SOURCE.pdp.isInHighDemandRegion = false;
    var _SPANLONG = pdp_location_data.longitude;
    var _SPANLAT = pdp_location_data.latitude;
    var _CENLONG = pdp_location_data.longitude;
   var _CENLAT = pdp_location_data.latitude;  </script>"""
soup = bsoup(source,"html.parser")


json_re = re.compile("SOURCE\.pdp\.propertyJSON\s+=\s+(\{.*\})\s+pdp_location_data")
scr = soup.find("script", text=re.compile("SOURCE.pdp.propertyJSON")).text
js_raw = json_re.search(scr).group(1)
json_dict = loads(js_raw)
```

Which would give you:

```
{u'numBeds': 2, u'neighborhood': u'Westwood', u'stateName': u'California', u'numFullBathrooms': 2, u'indexSource': u'Assessor', u'countyFIPS': u'06037', u'city': u'Los Angeles', u'isSrpFeatured': False, u'type': u'CONDO', u'formattedSqft': u'1,321 sqft', u'isOpaqueBAL': False, u'price': None, u'zipCode': u'90024', u'numBedrooms': u'2', u'neighborhoodId': 7187, u'county': u'Los Angeles', u'formattedBedAndBath': u'2bd, 2 full ba', u'sqft': 1321, u'numBathrooms': 2, u'stateCode': u'CA', u'isForeclosure': False, u'typeDisplay': u'Condo', u'foreclosureStatus': u''}
```

If you want the `pdp_location_data` json just apply the exact same logic.

Comment: Your solution works on my simplified example, and when I add the simplified example to another, longer script, but it doesn't work on the unsimplified original version. Woops! I'll update this comment and accept this as an answer once I've figured out where the divergence is. Most likely possibility: the json has a few elements with further sets of brackets, that I deleted,